# Different Instance of Applicationcontext in Broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, global-variables, broadcastreceiver

I want to access a "global" variable in my MyApp(extends Application) from a broadcastreceiver (registered in the manifest) and e.g. multiple activities. Now I seem to have different instances of my MyApp: one for the BCR and one for the activities. Could sb help me with my problem?
thanks alot
Joerg

Comment: How did you declare your "global" variable?

Comment: sure, its a member of my MyApp Class. I found a solution myself, but i still have a question: 
 <receiver android:name=".TestBroadcast2"></receiver> (in the manifest)works fine,
before I had
 <receiver android:process=":remote" android:name=".TestBroadcast2</receiver>
what does the android:process=":remote" do?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. How did you solve this?

Comment: "remote" runs in a separate process, so you will never see any Java objects created in the other process.
You should refrain from doing anything "meaningful" in `BroadcastReceivers` because they are on a "borrowed" thread (not your activity/service thread) and subject to ANR timer!  Do the minimum possible and send an `Intent` to a `Service` or `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

What I get from this is that you are trying to create a method to having a single Context object.  First off, to do this you would need a Singleton Pattern of MyApp to create your "global" variable.  However I would advice against this for these reasons:

1. Different application components by default have different contexts (base, application).
2. A BroadcastReceiver defined in the manifest is invoked by the OS, not by your application.
3. Using a Singleton Pattern for a context object will lead to some very nasty dependencies.
4. You are going against the design and beauty of the Android Framework.

I would suspect the reason you are doing this is so your MyApp class can start different activities.  This makes sense, but... you can get a Context Object from almost anywhere.  Many things in Android extend the ContextWrapper class (think Java Objects with the Object class).  So there is really no reason to ever have a "global" instance of this.  In fact your BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() method accepts a context parameter.  You can use this to start activities and what not.

If this is not why you are wanting the MyApp singleton class - and there are justifiable reasons for needing it, I would look at the [implementation designed by Bill Pugh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) as it is the safest in Java taking into account thread synchronization and locking.

Hope this helps.  Remember, don't fight the SDK, let it work for you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I was able to access an object in the activity using this pattern:

```
public class MyReceiver extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver {
    private Object _object;

    public MyReceiver(Someobject) {
        _object = the object;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Do something to the object.
    }
}
```

Then call `MyReceiver(theobject)` instead of `new BroadcastReceiver()`.